# How is the inlined methods mapped to assembly in Hotspot?

Tags: jvm

In this file are listed `JIT` compiler intrinsics [vmSymbols.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/cdf20166ec45/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp).

How are the inlined methods mapped to the corresponding CPU instructions in `Hotspot` ?

**Note:** I am looking for a specific inlined method `_getObjectVolatile` corresponding assembly code. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of HotSpot intrinsics are implemented in [library_call.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/5755b2aee8e8/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp#l814).

They are not mapped directly to assembly code, but rather to IR nodes in order to be platform-independent.

Comment: Could you please refer me to IR nodes doc ? what is IR abbreviation for ?

Comment: In this case  `case vmIntrinsics::_getAndAddInt:             return inline_unsafe_load_store(T_INT,    LS_xadd);` the second parameter is an asm instruction.

Comment: IR is intermediate representation. HotSpot uses 'sea of nodes' graph to model data and control flow. I doubt you find a good documentation on it, but you may try googling keywords like 'C2', 'HotSpot', 'ideal graph', 'sea of nodes' etc.

Comment: @Bionix1441 `LS_xadd` is not an instruction here, but just a `enum` constant that denotes the type of [load-store operation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/5755b2aee8e8/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp#l301).

Comment: There is part of Cliff Click PhD thesis about sea of nodes approach: http://grothoff.org/christian/teaching/2007/3353/papers/click95simple.pdf In my case it was very useful for understanding what's going on in /opto and /c1

Comment: Here is a good presentation http://fr.slideshare.net/RednaxelaFX/green-teajug-hotspotintrinsics02232013

Comment: I have look for `StringBuilder` Intrinsics implementation in the class `library_call.cpp` but I did't find them. I thought Intrinsified methods are native methods only.

Comment: @Bionix1441 Not only native methods. E.g. `Integer.reverseBytes` has Java implementation that is executed in interpreter mode, but as soon as JIT kicks in, the call is replaced with a single CPU intruction. `StringBuilder` intrinsics are treated specially in a separate phase. The corresponding code is in [stringopts.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/5755b2aee8e8/src/share/vm/opto/stringopts.cpp)